# Blue-green deployment for Jenkins itself

Tags: jenkins

When I tinker with my live Jenkins instance, I risk down time.  Thus I want to run blue and green Jenkins master instances.  This way, I can work on one while the other is live and stable.

As expected, searching on this topic tells me how to use Jenkins to do blue-green deployment of *other* applications.

Do you have any tips or references to give me a head start on setting up green and blue Jenkins masters?

Comment: Do you manage Jenkins with any configuration management tool puppet/chef/etc.?

Comment: No I do not.  I manage the configuration with git (not with the Jenkins SCM Sync Configuration plugin).